# Incisive Formal Verifier Installation 64 bit

Tags: testing, verilog, installation-package, formal-verification

Do you know IF i can run Cadence Incisive Formal Verifier in 64 BIT MODE ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your version, but for me :

```
$ ifv -help | grep 64
17:     +64bit                            Runs IFV in 64 bit mode
```

Launching it:

```
$ ifv temp.v
ifv: 10.20-s100:

$ ifv +64bit temp.v
ifv(64): 10.20-s100: //<-64 bit Version

setenv CDS_AUTO_64BIT
$ ifv temp.v
ifv: 10.20-s100:
```

CDS_AUTO_64BIT has no effect on the version I pick up.

Comment: should n't i write in command line setenv CDS_AUTO_64BIT  ??

Comment: My understanding, is that `setenv CDS_AUTO_64BIT` will set your default to use 64 bit. The command line option should override this. ie `ifv +64bit` should always give you 64 bit regardless.

Comment: which version of IFV do you use ??

Comment: INCISIV-10.20 ok understood !